# How to filter an Object in Javascript or Underscore with list of array elements as the key

Tags: javascript, algorithm, underscore.js

I have the following object and array, respectively.

```
cities = ['Berlin', 'Melbourne', 'Dallas']

population = { 'Amsterdam': 100, 'Berlin': 150, 'Cairo': 200, 'Jakarta': 300, 'Melbourne':350, 'Dallas': 400, 'Buenos Aires': 100}
```

And I would like to filter the population based on the *cities* mentioned in the array. The output will look as below.

*Order does not matter*

```
filtered_population = {'Berlin': 150, 'Melbourne':350, 'Dallas': 400}
```

What is the best way to do it with writing least amount of code?

Comment: Just found this http://underscorejs.org/#pick

_.pick(population, cities);

And it works like a charm!

Thanks everyone! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
var filterObj={};

cities.forEach(function(x){
  filterObj[x]=population [x];
});
console.log(filterObj);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/7e5s6s95/)**

Answer (score 2):

you can use reduce() to avoid a "side var":

```
var cities = ['Berlin', 'Melbourne', 'Dallas'],    
population = { 'Amsterdam': 100, 'Berlin': 150, 'Cairo': 200, 'Jakarta': 300, 'Melbourne':350, 'Dallas': 400, 'Buenos Aires': 100};

_.reduce(cities, function(a,b){ a[b]=population[b]; return a; },{});
// ==  {Berlin: 150, Melbourne: 350, Dallas: 400}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var filteredPopulation = _.object(
  _(population)
   .pairs()
   .filter(function(v) { return cities.indexOf(v[0]) !== -1 })
)
```